# AutoLayout: two UILabels with dynamic width; how to use preferredMaxLayoutWidth?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, autolayout

I've got two labels next to each other in a custom Table View Cell; the left one is multi line, the right one single line. I'd like to take the right label as much space as necessary, the left one the rest and doing a wrapping.

With Auto-Layout, I can only achieve this behavior if I set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the left label to a static value, e.g. 150. Then, it wraps as intended and I can calculate the cell's the following way:

```
[cell.leftLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize].height;
```

How can I avoid setting a fix preferredMaxLayoutWidth to the left label as it is dynamic?

Comment: Have you already solved this problem?